# How to sort multi-line row of table based on date

Tags: javascript, html

I am beginner to technologies like HTML, CSS, JavaScript at the moment and still learning.

I have been assigned a task to sort multi-line row of table based on "Exam date" in desc order with the help of JavaScript.

Actual table:

```
------------------------------------------------
| Id | Lastname    | Firstname    | Grade      | Standard |
| 23 | Doe         | John         | B+         | 7th      |
| Sex| Father Name | Mother Name  | Exam date  |
| M  | Tom Doe     | Dorina Doe   | 14.10.2013 |
| Id | Lastname    | Firstname    | Grade      | Standard |
| 27 | Reza        | Sasha        | A+         | 7th      |
| Sex| Father Name | Mother Name  | Exam date  |
| W  | Albert Reza | Sara Raza    | 17.10.2013 |
```

Expected table:

```
------------------------------------------------
| Id | Lastname | Firstname | Grade | Standard |
| 27 | Reza     | Sasha     | A+    | 7th      |
| Sex| Father Name | Mother Name  | Exam date  |
| W  | Albert Reza | Sara Raza    | 17.10.2013 |
| Id | Lastname | Firstname | Grade | Standard |
| 23 | Doe      | John      | B+    | 7th      |
| Sex| Father Name | Mother Name  | Exam date  |
| M  | Tom Doe     | Dorina Doe   | 14.10.2013 |
```

Comment: I did some formatting of the first table so the columns line up and it does not make sense... is this a table or two rows.... does the table actually have ID in the id column?

Comment: also it looks like the date is a string with day . month . year  is this the case?

Comment: It is a table with row expanding on next lines. The complete row with header and values would be [Id, Lastname, Firstname, Grade, Standard, Sex, Father Name, Mother Name , Exam date]. And date is a string thats correct !

Comment: We need to know how your HTML is structured, mainly those expanding rows. Also, are you using any framework o library? Are we supposed to just update the relevant parts of the table or we have to rerender it entirely? Is this table supposed to be paginated? Is the data of the table static or is it loaded everytime (for example, changes depending on logged user)? If it is loaded everytime you do it on backend or with ajax calls? I will likely have to answer all those questions and a few more before we can help you out.